# Openlayers map with chrome 34 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map with a large number of markers. Many of these markers are not appearing, but when I move the mouse over the area containing the missing markers, they appear. The page works perfectly in Firefox.

Comment: How many markers? Do you have any kind of strategy set? However, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help much without seeing a working example, ideally in jsFiddle.

Comment: As a matter of interest, did it work with earlier versions of Chrome?